# Pandas DF how to check in which column the value you are looking for is found

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two DF, I need to connect using df1[col_a] and df2 but the value may be in df2[col_a] or df2[col_b], I need to check where the value is. Help me.

```
merged_reports = pd.merge(sales_raport, credit_memo, left_on=["Invoice Number", "SanDisk Part Number"], right_on=["Invoice", "Debit MPN"])
```

"right_on=["Invoice"])" may be in the column "left_on=["Invoice Number"] or left_on=["Spi Number"]"

I tried:

```
if df1[col_a] == df2[col_a]:
   merged_reports = pd.merge(sales_raport, credit_memo, left_on= 
   ["Invoice Number", "SanDisk Part Number"], right_on=["Invoice", "Debit MPN"])
else:
   merged_reports = pd.merge(sales_raport, credit_memo, left_on= 
   ["SpiNumber", "SanDisk Part Number"], right_on=["Invoice", "Debit 
   MPN"])
```

and a few others but I always have various errors

Comment: Please provide a [mre] of your data for clarity and the matching expected output

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the values from df1[col_a] are present in either df2[col_a] or df2[col_b], and then merge accordingly.

```
import pandas as pd

# Assuming df1[col_a] represents the column in DF1 and col_a and col_b are the columns in DF2

merged_reports = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', left_on=col_a, right_on=col_a)

# Check if there are any NaN values in col_b of the merged DataFrame
merged_reports['col_b'].fillna(merged_reports[col_b], inplace=True)

# Drop the redundant col_b column
merged_reports.drop(columns=[col_b], inplace=True)

# merged_reports now contains the merged DataFrame
```

This code first merges df1 with df2 using col_a, then fills in missing values in col_b of the merged DataFrame using values from col_b if they are NaN. Finally, it drops the redundant col_b column.

Comment: No, I have one column in DF1 and the value from this column appears in DF2[col_a] or DF2[col_b] never in both